# Is it feasable to translate a Chinese HP Driver to english?

Tags: printers, printer-control-language

I apologize for the naivety of this question, I've some programming experience, but none writing drivers.

We have an older HP DesignJet 5000ps plotter. The only Windows 7 driver we were able to find for it is in Chinese... which works ok until we need to change the settings (there was an employee who spoke Mandarin, but he/she left).

I'm assuming, for the driver to work with windows properly, the source code is in English and simply the user interface is in Mandarin, so if I could access it, it would be a matter of changing the output for the various display options.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: According to this [other forum post elsewhere](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27244983/HP-Designjet-5000-64-Bit-Drivers-Can-5500-drivers-work.html), you should get away with the HP DesignJet 5500 drivers - or maybe [this link here](http://www.driverscape.com/download/hp-designjet-5000ps-42-by-hp) will help? Seems to be Win7 drivers - not sure about the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following link has the English driver you are looking for: 
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=58144

You can choose the language and the operating system version from the dropdown menus. If you have a newer Windows, you can run the software with XP compatibility settings if there are any problems.